# Using data out of the dataset recording mode in Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

Would it be possible to utilize the data that comes out of the Tango on a computer? I noticed that the datasets that are recorded are just ROS bags, but I'm not sure what the message types contain in each topic. Is there a resource that allows us to access the information contained in the bag?

EDIT: I'm talking about using the key: TANGO_DATASETRCORDING_MODE_ALL (https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/reference/TangoConfig.html#TANGO_DATASETRECORDING_MODE_ALL)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about recording the data on the Tango and exporting the dataset to a computer afterwards, but it's very much possible to stream the data to a *.csv* file over a WiFi connection.

As a simplified example, in the Tango's `onPoseAvailable()` callback, you can build a string that contains the *x, y* and *z* position of the Tango and fire off an ASyncTask class to write the position string to a WiFi port on your computer. On your computer you can have a simple script listening to that port which then writes whatever it receives into a .*csv* file. The WiFi write from the Tango's side will be triggered whenever `onPoseAvailable()` is called so you are effectively streaming the Tango's position in real-time.

Comment: Actually currently doing this right now. Was just curious if there was a way to hack the ADF datasets so we can look at the features extracted. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah I see the edit now. I was actually curious about what's inside the ADFs myself. Post the answer when you manage to figure it out :)